# Laravel passport oauth2 - How to login automatically after registration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I already implemented a Laravel passport oauth2 as server and integrated with my mobile application without the issue.

Laravel + vue(just default oauth page) integrate with JavaScript mobile application.

However, I trying to implement registration flow from my mobile application. The problem is.
My Laravel server will always redirect me to login page first if no authenticated then click authorize (already skipped this page with custom Passport client).

This is so far what I have tried

**Registration api**

```
public function first_register(Request $request)
{
$valid = validator([
    'domain' => 'required|unique:domains',
    'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
    'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Rules\Password::defaults()],
]);

if ($valid->fails()) {
    $jsonError = response()->json($valid->errors()->all(), 400);
    return response($jsonError, Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
}

User::create()......

if(! auth()->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])){
    return response()->json(['error' => 'UnAuthorised Access'], 401);
}
$client = Client::where('name', 'mobile-app')->first();
// create oauth redirect
$queries = http_build_query([
    'client_id' => $client->id,
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://'.$request->domain.'.localhost:3301/oauthcallback',
    'response_type' => 'code',
    'scope' => [],
    'state' => (string) Str::orderedUuid(),

]);
return response([
    'user' =>  $request->user(),
    'url'=>
    'http://'.$request->domain.'.localhost/oauth/authorize?' . $queries], Response::HTTP_OK);
```

}

The function above is working fine. The login page always will display after I clicked **oauth/authorize** url. Therefore, is there anywhere to skip this login page after register?

In addition, I also did try to use **Auth::login()** but still the same. Do I need to set session for Laravel passport API?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... is your default guard 'web'?

Comment: @lagbox Hi, yes. Default guard is 'oauth_web' but the auth->attempt() or Auth::login cant be use after changed to 'oauth_api'

Comment: Hello,
I'm trying to do the same.
My front Vue app sends a register request to my Laravel API (to create local user) which then sends another request to my Passport server API (to create remote user).

I'd like to have autologin after this flow.

I see 2 options : 
- respond an oauth_token to the front app (a bit hard to do programmatically in Passport and does not start a stateful session in Passport for future SSO needs)
- start a session for the newly created user, respond its session cookie and redirect to /login on front app to start oauth2 login flow

Did you achieve anything ?